# MySql Query, How to put conditon in Union query on same table

Tags: mysql, select

```
select * from 
(
   (select * from advertisement
    where fk_country='178' and ad_start_date <= '2016-03-14' and 
    ad_end_date>='2016-03-14' order by RAND() limit 3
   )

  UNION

  (select * from advertisement
   where  ad_start_date <= '2016-03-13' and ad_end_date>='2016-03-13' 
   order by RAND() limit 3
  ) 
)as leftpanelad order by rand() limit 3;
```

This query works very well and fetch three records.My question is if record for the first select query with fk_country exits than it should return three records from the first query only against that country id, the second query should return the balanced records if the records for the first query is less than three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select * from advertisement
where 
    case    when exists(select * from advertisement
                        where fk_country='178' and ad_start_date <= '2016-03-14' and 
                        ad_end_date>='2016-03-14' limit 2,1)
                then 
                    fk_country='178' and ad_start_date <= '2016-03-14' and 
                    ad_end_date>='2016-03-14'
            else 
                ad_start_date <= '2016-03-13' and ad_end_date>='2016-03-13' 
    end
limit 3;
```

Comment: Thanks @Dylan, I have one more question, if this record is for one column and also i needs records from the same table for second column with featured check, how i can avoid duplicates in both the columns?

Comment: I didn't quite understand the situation. basically, you can try to remove duplicates by 'DITSTINCT col1, col2'

Comment: See if i have 2 col on the main page, in one col i will display normal records and in 2nd i will display the featured from the same table.

Comment: have you tried adding DISTINCT before the select list?

Comment: for both columns i can run the query but how i can avoid the records that are already displayed in the first column?

Comment: Distinct i did not try, will it work if i am running two different queries?

Comment: For your original query, just use "select DISTINCT * from ". btw, does the query I posted work or not?

Comment: Simply if i run for first col "select * from advertisement" and for second column if i run "select * from advertisement where is_featured=1"  how i can avoid the duplicates in these two queries

Comment: UNION will remove the duplicates automatically.

Comment: i can understand the use of UNION for same div, in one div i will display 8 records and that may be or may not be featured, in another div i will display 8 records which are featured, so i want to remove duplication in two different div like if a record is displayed in first div, it should not appear in the featured div even if it is featured

Comment: For the second div query, you can add a where condition like " WHERE ... AND id NOT IN (first div select query)". Not elegant but should work.

Comment: Thank you for your response, let me check.